# Has scrollview event order changed in react native 0.20, ios?

Tags: react-native

I'm currently working with the scrollview component and make use of the different [callbacks for events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33924777/5339853) .

In version 0.19 the events came in the following order:

- onMomentumScrollBegin
- onScrollEndDrag
- onMomentumScrollEnd

This way, I could figure out if the user is doing a momentumScroll before onScrollEndDrag has been thrown and react to that accordingly.

Now, in react native 0.20 the order obviously changed to:

- onScrollEndDrag
- onMomentumScrollBegin
- onMomentumScrollEnd

Can someone explain that or point me to an url/issue/whatever/release note where I can verify that? I'm already looking for the changes but haven't found something so far.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.20.0) are the release notes for React Native 0.20.

There are references to ScrollView changes:

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/6941c4e027abb582d7cef0e7c3b9b7ebf51bc070)

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ee30433b7616a9807f38abd8c822c3f54c27dc39)

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/82b0df9d2a6163879647691235f01b3067c471b8)

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/b84f5fb6c9db79f378eed26c19e299d87c4852bf)

Not sure if you're using Android or iOS, but the above should point you in the right directions for any changes made in 0.20.

React Native Docs now have a version switcher, so you can now see the docs for each version:

[v 0.19 ScrollView docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.19/docs/scrollview.html#content)

[v 0.20 ScrollView docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#content)

Comment: Hey Nader, thank you so far. I've found those changes but I haven't spotted code possibly responsible for this change. I'm going to have a second look, though.